Bind Method and Remove of Event Listener in Stimulus Controller (JS)
I would like to ask a question about the class syntax in JavaScript and more specifically in the context of using Stimulus. Does anyone here know and use Stimulus, a framework that allows you to easily connect JavaScript to HTML via the data-controller attribute in HTML?
In all the documentation I have consulted on Stimulus, I have never seen the use of arrow functions. For example:
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.boundFindFoo)
  }

  findFoo() {
    console.log(this.element.querySelector("#foo"))
  }
}

What seems strange to me is that I never see a "bound" method in the constructor like:
this.boundFindFoo = this.findFoo.bind(this)
and secondly, I don't see a removeEventListener in the disconnect method (which runs when the DOM is unmounted).
I tried to explain to my colleagues that it would be more judicious to use arrow functions to have the functions automatically bound, but they told me that it worked without. Moreover, they were not convinced of the usefulness of removing event listeners in the disconnect method, because I do not have enough technical knowledge to justify it. I am personally more familiar with React and I know that when I use classes in React, I systematically bind my methods in the constructor (unless I use arrow functions) and I destroy the event listeners when the component is unmounted.
That's why I wanted to know if any of you technically know the reason to use or not use bind in a Stimulus controller and the usefulness or not of removing event listeners in the disconnect method.
Thank you in advance for your help.

My guess is there's a Proxy that handles boundXXX properties, automatically returning this.XXX.bind(this).
